# how to prove the solution to brainteaser "Urban planning"

Tags: graph-theory

"Urban planning" is a brainteaser asking: 
There are four towns positioned on the corners of a square. The towns are to be joined by a system of roads such that the total road length is minimized. What is the shape of the road?

well, the solution and question is as attached:

[image]

A,B,C,D are the 4 towns, dotted lines show the sequare, solid lines are the solution, $\angle AEB=\angle BFD = \frac{2}{3} \pi$.

It sounds convincing, but, how to prove *mathematically* the existence of the solution and, the valid of the solution?

Comment: This is known as the *Steiner Tree Problem*, if you look it up I am sure you can find a proof somewhere.

Comment: @David: How does one show that a finite set of additional points and edges is sufficient to model the solution space? (From an optimal perspective that is, clearly there are non optimal solutions that cannot be modelled by finite graphs.)

Comment: It's a basic optimisation problem to prove, given those five line segments, what their lengths must be to minimise the road length. It's shorter than any other configuration you can think of, which is convincing as you say, but I'm not sure how to prove how to prove the existence. Interesting question! +1

Comment: So any solution can be replaced by a straightline solution with $\le$ cost. Thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat Not being an expert in the field I'm not sure, that's the reason why I gave a reference rather than an answer ;)  However your comment is important, and it will certainly be addressed in any detailed discussion of the question.

Comment: @David: Gerry's pointer shows a straightforward reduction.

Comment: thanks! this question can be closed. indeed it's duplicated.